# Why won't my Google Chrome extension get loaded into the developer area of chrome://extensions?

Tags: javascript, json, intellij-idea, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am currently developing a Chrome extension. Whenever I attempt to load the manifest into the developer mode of chrome://extensions, an alert says that my value for "background.service_worker" is invalid and therefore the manifest cannot be loaded.

[image: the error message on chrome://extensions]
[image: the background.service_worker and content_script parts of my manifest, which don't load correctly]

I don't think that this is an issue with the code in the service worker, since changing the code itself has no effect. The only way my manifest can be loaded correctly is if I delete the background.service_worker and content_script parts of my manifest altogether.

This issue (the error with the exact same error message) occurs with any javascript file I put in the manifest. I've attached the relevant part of my manifest, as well as the error message. I use IntelliJ, if that's relevant. Any suggestions would be welcome as I've been thinking about this for days and am getting increasingly desperate. Thank you!

Comment: Try removing the brackets around `"background.js"`.

Comment: @ShawnOrr I'm going to cry thank you so much

Comment: We've all been there. :)